# Private enum with public overloaded constructor

Tags: c++, oop, enums, private

I am having issues getting my overloaded constructor to work. Keep getting an issue saying there is only a copy constructor and destructor. I am supposed to use a private enumeration techniques therefore using the member functions like `setWeaponSword()` (Last four functions).

Here is my class declaration:

```
class Knight{

public:
    enum Race{ ALTMER, IMPERIAL, KHAJIIT };
    Knight(Race newRace, short int newHealth, short int newStamina, Weapon newWeapon);
    Knight(const Knight &copiedKnight);
    ~Knight();
    void setRace(const Race newRace);
    Race getRace();
    void setHealth(const short int newHealth);
    short int getHealth();
    void setStamina(const short int newStamina);
    short int getStamina();
    void setWeaponBow();
    bool isWeaponBow();
    void setWeaponSword();
    bool isWeaponSword();
private:
    enum Weapon { BOW , SWORD};
    Race race;
    short int health;
    short int stamina;
    Weapon weapon;
};
```

Here is the simple member function file for it:

```
//Defualt values for variables Needed


 Knight::Knight(Race newRace, short int newHealth, short int newStamina, Weapon newWeapon) : newRace(IMPERIAL), newHealth(50), newStamina(35), newWeapon(SWORD)
{
    setRace(newRace);
    setHealth(newHealth);
    setStamina(newStamina);
}
```

My thought process is. I can't pass in a `Weapon` in main if I can't find it. That is why I am thinking i have to use the last four functions in my class to manipulate data to get it. I don't know how. Please let me know some basics.

Comment: What is the error and where does it occur? Also, it's pretty weird to have a copy ctor take it by non-const reference.

Comment: Maybe your compiler knows that Skyrim belongs to the Nords, and it flat out refuses to compile your program until you include them.

Comment: @JamesRoot Happens in my class declaration on the overloaded constructor.

Comment: Create a [mcve] that includes only the code necessary to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest doing this as a start:

```
private:
    enum Weapon { NO_WEAPON, BOW , SWORD};
    Race race;
    short int health;
    short int stamina;
    Weapon weapon{NO_WEAPON};
```

Then, you don't need to pass a weapon into the constructor.  The class will default to NO_WEAPON until you have one.

Consider removing the other parameters and replacing them with default values.  A constructor that takes a bunch of int's can be error prone.

Edit: If you're using an older compiler, you can't put {NO_WEAPON} int the class. Instead, you have to initialize it in your constructor:

```
     Knight::Knight(........) : weapon(NO_WEAPON)
     { ...
```

Comment: So I edited my constructor and I am know getting saying it does not know the datatype `weapon` on the line in my class file.